# Can I create a fixed size VHD that fills a physical hard drive up 100%?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, vhd

Would this create any foreseeable problems?  The drive is a non-system drive. Should I bother leaving any extra space on the physical drive that is not taken up by the VHD?

This may seem a bit silly, but I have an explicit need to mount a vhd instead of mounting the physical volume itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a system drive, then you shouldn't have any issues. The only catch you might find is that Windows might keep reminding you that the drive is full.

Comment: ok gotcha. hehe warnings should be ok, nobody is using the machine the vhd will be mounted on.

Comment: I agree that this should be the only problem, but there might be issues with the speed of the drive and the MFT, because you'll be consuming that reserved space too. I'm guessing though, because I've never done this.

Comment: ok I decided to leave 1gb free.. since even with a clean format 200meg was taken up from something. I assume 800mb should be enough for the MFT since there's really only 1 file on the physical disk, the vhd file.